# Cron Job executing on the wrong day

Tags: centos, scripting, cron

In the root users crontab on a Centos 7 server I have the following:

```
30 4 1-7 * * test $(date +\%u) -eq 7 && /usr/bin/needs-restarting -r || /usr/sbin/shutdown -r
```

It should run every day at 4:30 between the 1st and 7th day of the month, then it tests if the day of the week is Sunday and only then execute the next command to check if a reboot is required, and then reboot if it is. However my server rebooted today (1st Aug 2017) which is a Tuesday. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: If you're comfortable relying on a bug in cron (which will never be fixed), you can get rid of the test portion with the following schedule: [30 4 1-7 * */8](https://crontab.guru/#30_4_1-7_*_*/8) which ensures only first Sundays. So it would look like `30 4 1-7 * */8 /usr/bin/needs-restarting ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `a && b || c`, command `c` is executed when either `a` or `b` exit with a value other than 0. Consequently, when `test $(date +\%u) -eq 7` is false, your server reboots.

According to its name `/usr/bin/needs-restarting` probably returns 0 when the server needs a reboot. Are you sure that this should not be `a && b && c` instead?

Else, try `a && { b || c; }`

Comment: Thanks that explains it! 'needs-restarting -r' returns 1 if a reboot is needed so I think it is a '||' I need to use. 'a && { b || c; }' seems to do this trick for me. Thanks again!